# Is Java 1.6 the same as JDK 6?

Tags: java

I'm taking a computer science course and the syllabus says download java 1.6.  I don't find a java 1.6, everything says JDK 6.  When I googled java 1.6 I found this link:

http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp

Is this what he's refering to as java 1.6?  I downloaded JDK 6 update 17 and netbeans 6.8.  I'll email the instructor and ask him this question, but I bet I'll get quicker answer here and I'm ready to get started! Thanks!

update:
Thanks for the quick answers everyone! I'm rolling along now!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6_.28December_11.2C_2006.29

Comment: How many ages hence... Can I cross-post? I'll just cross-link for now. Check out my answer here, it fills in many details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250517/java-se-6-vs-jre-1-6-vs-jdk-1-6-what-do-these-mean/7247851#7247851

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java SE 6 vs. JRE 1.6 vs. JDK 1.6 - What do these mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250517/java-se-6-vs-jre-1-6-vs-jdk-1-6-what-do-these-mean)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, they're the same. See [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/version-6-141920.html) for a more detailed explanation of the version numbering.

Answer (score 45):

No, but yes.

JDK means Java Development Kit 6.

It's an implementation of the Java SE 6 platform as specified by [JSR 270](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=270) together with a set of development tools (the implementation of the platform without the development tools is called the JRE: Java Runtime Environment).

For some reason the internal version number of the JDK 6 is "1.6" (or 1.6.0_17 for example). But that's **only** the internal version number of that piece of software. The Java platform itself is simple "Java SE 6" (no "1." anywhere to see).

So to re-iterate:

- "Java 6" usually means "Java SE 6"
- "Java SE 6" is the "Java Standard Edition 6 platform", which is a specification of what the platform looks like
- "JDK 6" is the "Java Development Kit 6", which is a development kit for Java SE 6
- The **internal** version number of the software components that make up JDK 6 is "1.6.x"
- "JDK 1.6" doesn't exist, strictly speaking, but is usually written to refer to JDK 6
- "Java 1.6" doesn't exist, strictly speaking, but is usually written to refer to Java SE 6

So if you're told to install "Java 1.6" for a software development course, then the JDK 6 is definitely the correct piece of software to install.

*Update:* yes, all of the above is still correct after Oracle bought Sun and Java 7 (specified in [JSR 336](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=336)) was released. Java 7 *still* uses "1.7.0" as the *internal* version number.

Comment: @Mehrdad: granted, they did have brighter moments. On a positive note: now they seem to at least be consistent with the new scheme.

Comment: To be fair, Sun's version numbering has nothing on Emacs: version 23.2 and counting! (They skipped versions 2-12. According to the XEmacs website, at least.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Sun makes use of dual naming convention for the same thing. One naming convention if for the product and one is for the developer. The official [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/version-6.html) mentions:

> Both version numbers (1.6.0 and 6) are used to identify this release of the Java Platform. Version 6 is the product version, while 1.6.0 is the developer version. The number 6 is used to reflect the evolving level of maturity, stability, scalability and security of Java SE.

See [J2EE or JEE, Java 5 or Java 1.5 - Is SUN Crazy?](http://techtracer.com/2007/08/01/j2ee-or-jee-java-5-or-java-15-is-sun-crazy/) for more on this madness.

Madness...? This is Sun!

Answer (score 1):

They are the same.  Here is [Sun's discussion](http://java.sun.com/javase/namechange.html) of that and other naming discrepancies.