# Applet throwing exception when running it through web browser

Tags: java, applet, appletviewer

I have written an applet program. It has some references to classes from java tools.jar in it (eg:- import com.sun.jdi.connect.IllegalConnectorArgumentsException)

When I run this applet through appletviewer utility it works fine. But when I embed this applet in HTML file and try to run it through web browser, I am getting exception about some classes not found at runtime:-

`Java Plug-in 1.6.0_18

Using JRE version 1.6.0_18-b07 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

User home directory = C:\Documents and Settings\Pras`

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jdi/connect/IllegalConnectorArgumentsException
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jdi/connect/IllegalConnectorArgumentsException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$12.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jdi.connect.IllegalConnectorArgumentsException
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\pal\WTP_Workspace\JavaSocketBridge\bin\com\sun\jdi\connect\IllegalConnectorArgumentsException.class (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
... 17 more
Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jdi/connect/IllegalConnectorArgumentsException

However the IllegalConnectorArgumentsException class is part of java runtime located inside tools.jar.

How I can get run it inside browser as well?

many thanks in advance.

Regards,
Pras

Comment: Can you post the HTML for the applet?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve using that class?

Answer (score 1):

You are running your applet from the JRE. The class `IllegalConnectorArgumentsException` can only be access from the JDK since it's related to debugging.

Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250517/java-se-6-vs-jre-1-6-vs-jdk-1-6-what-do-these-mean).

Comment: Even when running from a JDK, the `tools.jar` would not by default be on the run-time class-path of an applet.

Comment: Then it's probably, the security restriction of the applet environment. The appletviewer has almost no restriction. You are not limited to the classes accessible and can open connection to any host for exemple (with the appletviewer).