# Eclipse ADT: Java was started but returned exit code=13

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

Could someone one clarify why my Eclipse (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) from ADT won't start?

Every time I'm getting this error:

```
---------------------------
Eclipse
---------------------------
Java was started but returned exit code=13
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.0.5-757759
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\Users\Alexey\Desktop\tmp\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher C:\Users\Alexey\Desktop\tmp\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library C:\Users\Alexey\Desktop\tmp\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807\eclipse_1503.dll
-startup C:\Users\Alexey\Desktop\tmp\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata bec_34
-product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.0.5-757759
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\Users\Alexey\Desktop\tmp\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13

Comment: What is the version of your eclipse and jre in terms of 32bit/64 bit

Comment: Java 1.6.0_39 64bit and Eclipse 86/64 ("adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729"). I checked pathes twices and found out that I pointed to 86 bit java version

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Error occurs when IDE(eclipse) bit-version (i.e. 32 or 64 bit) and jre bit-version mismatch! I have downloaded the 64 bit version and it showed me the exact error. But 32-bit version worked really fine. JRE version (1.6 or 1.7) doesn't matter. I think you dont need to downgrade. Because in my case, I had Java Version 1.7.0_45, whereas SDK requires 1.6, but it still worked perfectly fine!

Comment: Eclipse is not an SDK (Software Development Kit); it is an IDE (Integrated Development Environment). The Java SDK, or JDK, is the only SDK used in Java development.

Answer (score 6):

**Remove** the following entry from your **"path"** System Variable-
**"C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath"**

Go to Control panel -> System -> Environment variable -> System Variable -> Path (Edit)

then Remove first entry which would be **"C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath"**.

Then eclipse will start.

Comment: You are my saviour, Raj

Answer (score 4):

> "Java was started but returned exit code=13"

error is caused when you are attempting to start Eclipse using the wrong version of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

Here are some recommendations to correct this error:

http://www.ehow.com/how_4784069_terminated-exit-code-error-eclipse.html

Comment: I have 1.7 (the latest) and required is 1.6. Have to downgrade. 
was java version "1.7.0_25"
now java version "1.6.0_39". I was able to run Eclipse now. Thanks!

Comment: johnshumon's answer is the correct one, no need to downgrade, just download eclipse at 32 or 64 bit, depending on the bitness of your installed java

Comment: Is this link's answer really correct? Because I think is should be pointed out that the problem is (specifically) which JDK you have. For example, I recently upgraded to Java 8, but neglected to get the Java 8 JDK. As soon as I had the Java 8 JDK, everything worked fine. This is what @Art pointed out.

You can have the JVM but not the JDK right? I'm not sure, but was looking at this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547458/what-is-the-difference-between-jvm-jdk-jre-openjdk). If somebody wants to clarify, please do.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall all Java SDK or JRE, specially if it´s the **8th** version, so reinstall the **6th** or **7th** version, and check again. It worked for me :)

Comment: I had this problem, I uninstalled 8th version and now it is working with 7th, maybe it is a problem of ADT with 8th version

Answer (score 1):

Check that the version being used by Eclipse is same as shown in your error code. If not, call that version explicitly.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -version
```

Comment: 1.7 (the latest) and required is 1.6. Have to downgrade. Thanks! 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have not specified the path to the javaw.exe file which is in jdk.

1. open eclipse.ini file
2. after vmargs command(ie below the vmargs command - since they have to be in separate lines)
   add the following line
   -vm 
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javaw.exe
   NOTE : that the -vm shud b in one line and the path to the javaw.exe file must be in another line
3. save the file
4. run the eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after updating my JRE.  I downloaded the latest JDK and the problem was fixed.   The JRE has to match the JDK for Eclipse to run.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows `Environment Variables`, delete the value of Path variable that contains installed Java location. Then copy the installed Java to your Android-SDK folder.

You can copy the jre folder (example `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre`) to

```
C:\Users\Alexey\Desktop\tmp\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\eclipse\
```

It solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

this happened to me as well due t mismatch in 64-bit eclipse and 32-bit java. in my case the problem was that I had downloaded java from 32-bit chrome browser (java download probably picks up 32/64 bit architecture from browser details - not sure), even though was using 64 bit windows.

Solution that worked for me...

1) uninstall java

2) restart system

3) navigate to the java download page

4) instead of choosing "Agree and Start Free Download", look for "See all Java downloads"

5) Click on the link and choose appropriate java version that matches your OS

6) install java

7) install eclipse.

done!

Answer (score 1):

this is a makeshift solution but may sort you out.

show hidden files, C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

you will find 3 shortcut links that are pointing to the wrong directories,

solution 1; go to C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin and copy out the files these links are pointing to and paste into the C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath. Close and run again the eclipse, install updates

solution 2: go fix the environmental paths as some other solutions here suggest.

the first one worked for me

Answer (score 0):

A few more checks...

Ensure you remove all older versions of Java. Having multiple versions of the Java Runtime will cause this error. Also check what OS you are using. Is it 32-bit or 64-bit? You need to install the appropriate version of the Java runtime. You cannot run ADT/Eclipse on a 64 bit OS with a 32-bit Java runtime. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be found [here](http://www.ashout.com/fix-java-started-returned-exit-code13-eclipse/)

The eclipse ini file should be somewhat like this...

```html
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
adtproduct
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error is because your Eclipse and JDK versions are different. Solution is simple. Define what your JDK bin folder is and use *eclipse -vm JDK_bin_path* command.

Example:
In my case a folder is *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin* 
Then right click on your Eclipse.exe file, select *Shortcut* tab, in *Target* field, right after eclipse.exe, write -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin"

That's all. Let me know if you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Only add following two line at top of eclipse.ini :-

---

```
 -vm

 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin/javaw.exe
```

***Note***: Replace 'jdk1.7.0_60' with your installed version

Answer (score 0):

If you still getting same error after trying all solution described here, then try to move your whole eclipse folder in the drive (D:) another than the drive ( C:) where you have installed your jdk. This worked for me