# Java exit code 13 - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, exit

my eclipse was working just fine, then one day (My computer may have done some automatic updates, I'm not sure) my eclipse ended up not starting up anymore and this kept popping up:

[image]

This is my version of java

[image]

Any help or solutions would be greatly appreciated! ^^

Comment: This almost always means you have a 64 bit Eclipse and a 32 bit Java (or the other way round). They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Comment: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4945178/1391249), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11461607/1391249), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6166795/1391249), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18349517/1391249)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13) answer. You probably have to edit something in your `eclipse.ini` file.

The guy who answered his question claims that the `.ini` file contains the following instructions.

```
 1. The -vm option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.
 2. The value must be the full absolute path to the Java executable, not just to the Java home directory.
 3. The -vm option must occur before the -vmargs option, since everything after -vmargs is passed directly to the JVM
```

Check out those steps above and check out the other SO thread.