# What is the difference between -Xss and -XX:ThreadStackSize?

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I just want to control the stack size for all of my threads in a Java (groovy) application. For the Hotspot Oracle VM, I know that there are two parameters doing that  ([`-Xss`](http://www.onkarjoshi.com/blog/209/using-xss-to-adjust-java-default-thread-stack-size-to-save-memory-and-prevent-stackoverflowerror/) and [`XX:ThreadStackSize`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)).

Which is the preferred one? Is there any difference between them? Regarding Open JDK 7 [someone asked on the mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-dev/2011-June/004272.html), stating that `-Xss` is the same for the Hotpot VM as `-XX:ThreadStackSize`.

The point is, that I am measuring how many threads can be started on my system.
My groovy script which does this looks like:

```
int count = 0

def printCountThreads = {
     println("XXX There were started $count threads.")
}

try {
    while(true){
            new Thread({Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE)}).start()
            count++
            if(count % 1000 == 0){
                    printCountThreads()
            }
    }
} catch (Throwable e){
    printCountThreads()
    throw e
}
```

Interestingly enough I just get a reduced number of of threads using -`XX:ThreadStackSize`. I am starting the groovy application with and with different content in the environment variable JAVA_OPTS.

```
groovy countmax-threads.groovy
```

When I set JAVA_OPTS to `-XX:ThreadStackSize=2m`, I get about 1000 started threads until the memory is consumed. But, when I use `JAVA_OPTS='-Xss2m'`, I get about 32000 threads until the expected error arises. So it seems that `-Xss` does not work at all.

I am using

> java version "1.8.0_05"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

on a Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit machine with four hardware threads and about 8 GB of RAM.

UPDATE:

I reverified this on my Windows 7 64 bit machine and another JDK:

> java version "1.8.0_20"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)

and there `-Xss` and `-XX:ThreadStackSize` work as expected (as some answers pointed out). So I suppose it is a Linux specific problem or even a bug in the JDK version 1.8.05.

Comment: Maybe someone can verify on his machine with an other vm? I used groovy 2.3.9 for the script...

Comment: Same behaviour on linux:
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
Seems to me like a linux specific JVM problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-Xss` is standard options recognized by the Java HotSpot VM.

`-XX:ThreadStackSize` as other `-XX` options are not stable and are subject to change without notice.

See [Java HotSpot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

Comment: Than why there behaviour differs?

Comment: @user2078148 Dis you download the java hotspot from Oracle? The link where it's stated that -Xss and -XX:ThreadStackSize are equivalent is about openjdk. Openjdk and Oracle Hotspot VM might differ. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11580321/1140748. So  -XX:ThreadStackSize that might fail because -XX options are not stable.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion... but why than -XX:ThreadStackSize=2m just works and -Xss does not?

Comment: Oracle Java SE 8 docs suggest they are exact synonyms:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html

Comment: Hi @AlanThompson, yes this might be possible, but it can change. If you can use an option not starting with -XX, then do it. -XX options are not stable and are subject to change without notice.

Answer (score 8):

`-Xss` is an alias for `-XX:ThreadStackSize` both for OpenJDK and Oracle JDK.

Though they parse arguments differently:
`-Xss` may accept a number with K, M or G suffix;
`-XX:ThreadStackSize=` expects an integer (without suffix) - the stack size in kilobytes.

Comment: Well I don't encountered any problems in specifing -XX:ThreadStackSize=2m, altrough you are right, the docs say what you told me ... but this all makes it not clear

Comment: Oracle Java SE 8 docs suggest they are exact synonyms:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html

Comment: Thanks. When I provided "-Xss3m" as JAVA_OPTS but the GC logs printed "-XX:ThreadStackSize=3072". 3072 does not have any prefix and I was looking for confirmation that size is in kilobytes.

Answer (score 4):

### UPDATED 2019 for Java SE 8

Current Oracle Java SE 8 docs suggest that `-Xss` and `-XX:ThreadStackSize=size` are equivalent.  See
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html

---

### For `-Xss`:

```
-Xsssize  

   Sets the thread stack size (in bytes). Append the 
   letter k or K to indicate KB, m or M to indicate MB, g or G to 
   indicate GB. The default value depends on the platform:

Linux/ARM (32-bit): 320 KB

Linux/i386 (32-bit): 320 KB

Linux/x64 (64-bit): 1024 KB

OS X (64-bit): 1024 KB

Oracle Solaris/i386 (32-bit): 320 KB

Oracle Solaris/x64 (64-bit): 1024 KB

The following examples set the thread stack size to 1024 KB in different units:

-Xss1m
-Xss1024k
-Xss1048576 

This option is equivalent to -XX:ThreadStackSize.
```

---

### For `-XX:ThreadStackSize=size`

```
-XX:ThreadStackSize=size 

  Sets the thread stack size (in bytes). Append the 
  letter k or K to indicate kilobytes, m or M to indicate 
  megabytes, g or G to indicate gigabytes. The default 
  value depends on the platform:

Linux/ARM (32-bit): 320 KB

Linux/i386 (32-bit): 320 KB

Linux/x64 (64-bit): 1024 KB

OS X (64-bit): 1024 KB

Oracle Solaris/i386 (32-bit): 320 KB

Oracle Solaris/x64 (64-bit): 1024 KB

The following examples show how to set the thread stack size to 1024 KB in different units:

-XX:ThreadStackSize=1m
-XX:ThreadStackSize=1024k
-XX:ThreadStackSize=1048576 

This option is equivalent to -Xss.
```

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle Java SE 8 docs suggest that -Xss and -XX:ThreadStackSize=size are equivalent.
However this not correct. Try eg.

```
java -XX:ThreadStackSize=1024 -version
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

java -Xss1024 -version
The stack size specified is too small, Specify at least 160k
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

This is fixed e.g. in the [Java 14 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/java.html):

> -XX:ThreadStackSize=size
> Sets the Java thread stack size (in kilobytes). Use of a scaling suffix, such as k, results in the scaling
> of the kilobytes value so that -XX:ThreadStackSize=1k sets the Java
> thread stack size to 1024*1024 bytes or 1 megabyte.

and

> -Xss size
> Sets the thread stack size (in bytes).

Answer (score 1):

`-Xss` works only on `main` Java thead, but `-XX:ThreadStackSize` works on all Java thread.

> If -Xss (or -ss) were passed on the command line,
>   it gets picked up directly by the launcher and is used later to create the
>   "main" Java thread, without asking the VM for the preferred thread stack
>   size. That where inconsistency comes from:
>    if -Xss is given after -XX:ThreadStackSize, then things are still good;
>    otherwise, the "main" Java thread would have a stack size specified by -Xss
>   where as other Java threads' stack size would still follow that of
>   ThreadStackSize.

[Inconsistency between -Xss and -XX:ThreadStackSize in the java launcher](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-dev/2011-July/004288.html)

Comment: The cited mailing list post seems to apply for JDK 6 and 7. For JDK 8, I will verify that on my local machine again. You hint was really useful, thank you!

Comment: Well after studying the mailing list post by Kris Mok in detail, I have to correct you. -Xss will work for the thread stack size as -XX:ThreadStackSize too. The problem arises when you are using both at the same time (in the order -Xss -XX:ThreadStackSize). In this case, the vm will pick up the value specified in -Xss only for the main thread and the value specified in -XXThreadStackSize for all other user threads. Those two options should be equivalent! One has to be careful when using both (which usually does not make any sense)