# What is threshold limit number of threads that a JVM can create

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

**Edit:**

As what @Petesh said, I reached the `kern.num_taskthreads` limit rather than the overall thread limit, which limits the number of threads for an individual process.

The `sysctl kern.num_taskthreads` is:

```
kern.num_taskthreads: 2048
```

And when I used the VM args, `-XX:ThreadStackSize=1g`, I could only create *122* threads; with `-XX:ThreadStackSize=2g`, *58* threads was created. It's reasonable.

But it's still strange that no matter how I changed the `-Xss` args, the result is always *2031*. The `-Xss` args seems only works for main thread which I'm not sure for now.

**Original question:**

I ran a test to find out how many threads that one JVM can create. And when I adjusted the JVM args, `-Xmx` and `-Xss`, the result didn't change.

Here is the code:

```
public class ThreadTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        try {
            while (true) {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(360);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                thread.start();
                System.out.println(count);
            }

        } catch (Error e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the OS info:

> - Model Name:  MacBook Pro
> - Model Identifier:    MacBookPro11,4
> - Processor Name:  Intel Core i7
> - Processor Speed: 2.2 GHz
> - Number of Processors:    1
> - Total Number of Cores:   4
> - L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
> - L3 Cache:    6 MB
> - Memory:  16 GB

The java version:

```
➤ java -version                                                                                                                                                          
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b01-dcevmlight-1, mixed mode)
```

The result: 
[image]

The `ulimit -a`:
[image]

The `sysctl kern.num_threads`:

```
kern.num_threads: 10240
```

Comment: It sounds like you're bumping into the `kern.num_taskthreads` limit rather than the overall thread limit, which limits the number of threads for an individual process. This value is *not* a tunable, without effort.

Comment: By design whatever limits there are will be a platform-specific implementation detail. Whatever numbers or answers you get, don't expect them to be stable across platforms or Java releases.

Comment: @Petesh You are right. One more question, did linux have such similar limitation?

Comment: Linux doesn't have a per-process thread limit per-se. The max number of processes would effectively set a thread limit for the user; and the `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` is the overall limit.

Comment: @Petesh I just made another test with VM args, `-XX:ThreadStackSize=4g`, and got the error when I created 24 threads; But when I use `-Xss4g`, then I got the error when I created 2032 threads. Do you have any ideas about the differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All this stuff is OS specific - in the case of OSX, you've got a per-process thread limit that can't be exceeded from the `sysctl kern.num_taskthreads`. The limit in number of threads that you created and the overhead of VM created threads seems to indicate that you're reaching that limit.

The difference between `-XX:ThreadStackSize` and `-Xss<size>` is a bit odd. In this case I'm basing my analysis on the OSX oracle java vm (you're indicating that you're running with a different VM).

`-Xss` sets the stack size to *that number of bytes*. The variable storing it divides it by 1024. However because of the way it calculates it the value ends up as a meaningless value (64bit jvm, checked on linux and osx) - this is some vonderfully bad overflow math:

```
for i in {1..8}; do echo "${i}G:"; java -Xss${i}g -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version 2>&1 | grep ' ThreadStack'; done
1G:
     intx ThreadStackSize                          := 1048576                             {pd product}
2G:
     intx ThreadStackSize                          := 18014398507384832                    {pd product}
3G:
     intx ThreadStackSize                          := 18014398508433408                    {pd product}
4G:
     intx ThreadStackSize                          := 0                                   {pd product}
5G:
     intx ThreadStackSize                          := 1048576                             {pd product}
6G:
     intx ThreadStackSize                          := 18014398507384832                    {pd product}
7G:
     intx ThreadStackSize                          := 18014398508433408                    {pd product}
8G:
     intx ThreadStackSize                          := 0                                   {pd product}
```

When we compare this with `-XX:ThreadStackSize` we have a different picture:

Firstly, these values are scaled by a factor of 1024 - i.e. all values requested are actually a number of KB for the stack size.

This means that `-XX:ThreadstackSize` needs to be specified in a factor of 1024 down from the values from `-Xss`. The fact that you were only able to create a fraction of the number of threads, and the virtual memory size of the process makes this obvious (taken from the vmmap output of the process):

```
Stack                  0000000800004000-0000040800000000 [  4.0T] rw-/rwx SM=NUL  thread 23
Stack                  0000040800000000-0000040800003000 [   12K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  thread 23
```

4TB per stack? That's going to hurt (this is what you'd previously asked for):

Once we adjust it down by a factor of 1024, we get the same number of threads in the second run - you can see these numbers far more clearly in the output and they linearly scale with the requested size:

```
for i in {1..8}; do echo "${i}G:"; java -XX:ThreadStackSize=${i}m -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version 2>&1 | grep ' ThreadStack'; done
1G:
     intx ThreadStackSize                          := 1048576                             {pd product}
2G:
     intx ThreadStackSize                          := 2097152                             {pd product}
3G:
     intx ThreadStackSize                          := 3145728                             {pd product}
4G:
     intx ThreadStackSize                          := 4194304                             {pd product}
5G:
     intx ThreadStackSize                          := 5242880                             {pd product}
6G:
     intx ThreadStackSize                          := 6291456                             {pd product}
7G:
     intx ThreadStackSize                          := 7340032                             {pd product}
8G:
     intx ThreadStackSize                          := 8388608                             {pd product}
```

So, it looks like using `-Xss<size>` is really only useful when you're looking for a stacksize of < 1GB; and if you're looking for a stacksize of > 1GB then you can specify it explicitly with `-XX:ThreadStackSize`.

Figuring out the overflow. The code that [parses the Xss option](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/81d815b05abb/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l2230):

```
julong long_ThreadStackSize = 0;
ArgsRange errcode = parse_memory_size(tail, &long_ThreadStackSize, 1000);
```

Then in an act of **stellar muppetry** [it does](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/81d815b05abb/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l2239):

```
FLAG_SET_CMDLINE(intx, ThreadStackSize,
                          round_to((int)long_ThreadStackSize, K) / K);
```

i.e. downcasts the `long` to an `int`, which it then passes to `round_to`. This takes a `Register` value, which is a 64bit value on the 64bit VM. So from what I can tell is that it the value you start with is:

```
0x80000000
```

Gets [sign extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) to:

```
0xFFFFFFFF80000000
```

This gets divided by 1024 (0x400):-

```
0x3FFFFFFFE00000 == 18,014,398,507,384,832
```

so you can see where the 2GB value in the prior script comes from.

I've logged a bug. The change needed in the source is rather than `(int)long_ThreadStackSize` it should be `(Register)long_ThreadStackSize` to keep the calculation correct.

Comment: I used the `HotSpot VM` too, just with a [DCE VM](http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/) installed. I ran your code and got the same result. But I still couldn't understand it. It seems some overflow happened. I have tried to read the source code referred to by the mail list: [What the difference between -Xss and -XX:ThreadStackSize is?](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-dev/2011-June/004272.html).  And I didn't find out where the overflow happened.

Comment: I added a couple of paragraphs on how the overflow comes about - it's a sign extension bug causes by casting the long value into an int, and then having sign-extension turn it into a huge value.

Comment: I am not really familiar with `C++`, so can you tell me where could I find the definition of `round_to` function? It seems be a very obvious bug in the code...

Comment: And what the type `Register ` means? Is it an unsigned long value?

Comment: It's [defined in this file](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/hs-dev/hotspot/file/ae5624088d86/src/cpu/x86/vm/macroAssembler_x86.cpp#l3816) for x86 platforms. The class `Register` corresponds to a 32bit value when run in 32bit code, and a 64bit value when run in 64bit code. The bug is in the calling of `round_to` - the explicit cast to `int` followed by `C++`'s sign extension when calling the routine to create a `Register` is what mangles the value and that's got nothing to do with the actual code of `round_to`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I understand if an `int` cast to `unsigned long` value, the sign extension would happen. But how is it possible? I know that if I called a method with an `int` value as parameter who's definition is `void round_to(long num)`, the `int` value will implicit cast to `long` type first in Java. But these won't happen between a primitive type and a custom type. If `Register` is a user defined class, how could implicit cast happen? Is this a different between `Java` and `C++`?

Comment: No, an `int` cast to a `signed long` would cause the sign extension. You can define constructors that will convert from one data type to the class in question in `C++`. In this case, the data type that's being used is not `unsigned long` but `intptr_t`, a signed equivalent to the size of a pointer. I've made a little C++ example to illustrate the sign extension - http://cpp.sh/8z3id note that sign extension only applies when extending a signed value into a signed data type, if it's going to be unsigned then you don't get sign extension.

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake here. So after the sign extension happened, the value `0x80000000` became `0xFFFFFFFF80000000` which was still a signed value. Then when it was divided by 1024, the result `0x3FFFFFFFE00000` was a signed value either. But at last, we got an positive value `18,014,398,507,384,832`. How this happened? Was there another cast here?

Comment: Because the top bit of the final value was not `1`, it was interpreted as a really big positive number. If the top bit of the final value was a `1`, then it would be interpreted as a negative number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113592/discussion-between-little-pig-and-petesh).

Answer (score 1):

I test it on my linux jvm 1.8.0_92, it's same as what you said, and I find this:

[What is the difference between -Xss and -XX:ThreadStackSize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767905/what-is-the-difference-between-xss-and-xxthreadstacksize)

And the oracle page:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html

it says:

The following examples set the thread stack size to 1024 KB in different units:

```
   -Xss1m
   -Xss1024k
   -Xss1048576
```

`This option is equivalent to -XX:ThreadStackSize`

Comment: Yes it said so, but the result is different. That's strange.

Comment: Yes, the article about `difference between ...` said jvm on windows is ok

Comment: @little.Pig I tried Xss2g and XX:ThreadStackSize=2g in linux, both could not create the vm, but the first shows `intx ThreadStackSize                          := 18014398507384832` and the other shows ` intx ThreadStackSize                          := 2147483648`. It's more complicated than I think.

Comment: On my 64bit linux VM, I could create the JVM with `-Xss10239m` but not with `-Xss10240m`; and I could create the JVM with `-XX:ThreadStackSize=6m` but not with `-XX:ThreadStackSize=7m`. The `ulimit -a` is `stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240`. It was odd.