# Performance on Oracle JDK and OpenJDK

Tags: performance, java

I have Oracle JDK7(JavaSE Hotspot Embedded JRE) and OpenJDK7(Cacao,JamVM,ZeroVM). 
Platform is : PPC32 Embedded Platform (e550)

I have run simple prime number java application with both java. 
As coclusion Oracle JRE is much faster than open jdk with cacao or jamvm or zero VM.

I am looking to improve the execution speed with openjdk. Need the excecution time same as oracle JRE.
How can I improve the execution speed of java application (single or multithread).

Which are the component different in Oracle and Open JDK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between JVM, JDK, JRE & OpenJDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547458/what-is-the-difference-between-jvm-jdk-jre-openjdk)

Comment: @J91321 I think OP is aware of the difference between the implementations and has a specific target.

Comment: You really do need to post the code which you base your results on.