# Can't run JAR file

Tags: java, executable

I have a finished program that I created a JAR executable from (I created this in eclipse), and I need to download this executable onto computers different from the one that I wrote the program on.

However, I am getting the problem that when I try and download the executable onto the computers, I get the window that pops up that says that "Windows can't open this file" and it then gives me a list of programs that I can open the file with, none of which I can use. I do not need to do this on the computer on which I wrote the program. When I double-click the executable on that computer, the program starts without any trouble.

Comment: Is Java installed on the other computer?

Comment: Do you mean the runtime environment?

Comment: Java doesn't come with Windows, and if your .jar file runs on your pc by double-clicking it, it's because it's got a file association and a classpath set in the environment. None of those things happen by default, which is probably why it's not working on any other PCs.

Answer (score 2):

In order to run Java programs, you have to install the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). The Java Development Kit (JDK) is not needed. You can download the [latest version (JRE) here](https://www.java.com/download/).

If you want to learn more about JVM, JRE and JDK, you can read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547458/what-is-the-difference-between-jvm-jdk-jre-openjdk).

Answer (score -2):

This is cause you need install Java in the remote machines including the JDK, then also you need to make java available through console installing Ant wherever it applies.

Comment: "...also you need to make java available through console installing Ant wherever it applies."  I don't understand what you mean by this.

Comment: You don't need the JDK to run .jars, just the JRE. You also don't need ant, though if you're going to use ant, it needs the JRE.