# what is the difference between different java JDK files: default-java , java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 , java-8-openjdk-amd64 , java-8-oracle

Tags: java, android-studio, java-8

they are all in my /usr/lib/jvm/.. file in my ubuntu machine. Can someone explain the differences between these 4 files and why the file called java1.8.0_91 isn't considered a JDK? I came across these files while finding a JDK for android studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of these directories are [symlinks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/symbolic-link) to each other. You, probably, have two JDK/JRE installed: Open JDK and Oracle JDK. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22358234/2842067) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11580321/2842067) for difference between Open JDK/Oracle JDK, and between JDK and JRE. `java1.8.0_91` is probably JRE, not JDK.