# How javac works while importing a package?

Tags: java, jdk1.7

I am having a doubt.
My understanding is that `jdk` has [ `jre` + development tools (Java, javac, debugger etc.) + source code (src.zip) ].

Now working of java compiler is nothing to do with the running of class file.

If I am compiling a `.java` file then from where the java compiler is importing the package?
I could find the packages under `jre`.
If I do not opt to install `jre` while installing `jdk`, does that mean I will not be able to compile the java file having import statement?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as a minor remark, a statement like

```
import java.util.List;
```

just introduces an abbreviation, allowing you to use the simple word `List` later in your code instead of the full class name `java.util.List`. So it's not so much the import statement itself, but the usage of a class like `java.util.List` that needs some explanation.

You understand correctly that, to compile your java file, the compiler needs some information about every class you use, and it typically finds this information in some jar file containing that class.

Now, where is this jar file containing the `java.util.List` class that the compiler reads? You're correct, it comes from the JRE, from the `rt.jar` that's part of the system classpath (the Java compiler itself is a java program that needs the basic classes itself, so wherever you successfully run `javac`, you always have an `rt.jar` available).

If your source code used a class from some other library, you'd have to specify that library on the `javac` command line, using an option like `-cp`.

Comment: Thanks @Ralf. Do we not have option to install jdk without jre? If so, can we run the java compiler then?

Comment: The JDK always contains a JRE, it can't operate without one. What was optional was to additionally install a publicly available JRE that could be used for non-JDK purposes.

Answer (score 0):

`Jdk = JRE + other tools like you mentioned.`
When you are compiling your java file and you are using java inbuild library then it uses `rt.jar` to resolve dependency i.e import statements.
You can refer below link for the difference
[What is the difference between JVM, JDK, JRE & OpenJDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547458/what-is-the-difference-between-jvm-jdk-jre-openjdk)