# Why JVM is called virtual machine and JRE is not called virtual machine?

Tags: java

I am not able to find proper explanation. I could find reasons for why JVM is called virtual machine but not for why jre is not called as virtual machine . Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between JVM, JDK, JRE & OpenJDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547458/what-is-the-difference-between-jvm-jdk-jre-openjdk)

Comment: The JVM is to the JRE what the motor is to a car: it is a part of it. And while the JVM is a virtual machine we don't call the JRE a virtual machine for similar reasons as we don't say a car is a motor.

Comment: Hi adwaita, Have you seen my answer? Did you find it helpful? I'll be so happy to give me some feedbacks, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The differences of `JVM` and `JRE` , including the reason why `JVM` is not called a `virtual machine` as opposed to `JVM`:

- The `JRE` is an abbreviation for `Java Runtime Environment`, where as the The `JVM` is an abbreviation for `Java Virtual Machine`.
- ###### Defenition:

  - The `Java Runtime Environment (JRE)` is an implementation of `JVM`.
    It is a type of software package that provides `class libraries` of
    `Java`, `JVM`, and various other components for running the
    applications written in Java programming.
  - The `Java Virtual Machine (JVM)` is a platform-independent abstract
    machine that has three notions in the form of specifications.
- ###### Funcionality:

  - `JRE` has a major responsibility for creating an environment for the execution of code.
  - `JVM` specifies all of the implementations. It is responsible for providing all of these implementations to the `JRE`.

I hope you understood why `JRE` is not called a `virtual machine`.