# Why do some Java programs ask for a JDK and some for the JRE?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java SE 6 vs. JRE 1.6 vs. JDK 1.6 - What do these mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250517/java-se-6-vs-jre-1-6-vs-jdk-1-6-what-do-these-mean)

I found that sometimes applications ask for `java_home` to point to a JDK and won't work with a JRE.

Why is that the case? Is it correct?

Comment: When you ask a question, some duplicates are listed. Check them.

Comment: I **strongly** disagree with the duplicate question listed. This is a much more specific question than "what's the difference between a JRE and a JDK?".

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Agreed. Some tools (Maven) assume javac (in tools.jar) under java_home, others don't. It's important to distinguish between them. Question is valid.

Comment: Requiring the JDK makes only sense for java compilation, so applications like IDEs, JEdit and such.

Comment: @dystroy: still not enough.

Comment: @dystroy: I tried to, but did not find a valid duplicate. Feel free to correct me (and I'll vote for it) if you find one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short version:** some applications use libraries/code that is contained *only* in the JDK.

**Longer version:** *Usually* every Java program should be able to run with just the JRE. And most applications actually work with the JRE.

Now the JDK comes with some additional libraries and tools that you *usually* only need when *developing* applications (and not when you simply need to run them).

But occasionally an application decides to use some of the code that gets delivered with the JDK *when it runs*. It's very rare and is usually not a good idea (unless that application is itself about developing Java applications).

A good example where old versions of Apache Tomcat: it used the Java compiler bundled with the JDK to compile JSP code into bytecode. For this it used `tools.jar` which is included in the JDK but doesn't get delivered with the JRE.

Newer Tomcats switched to a separate compiler (I think it's based on the Eclipse compiler) for this and no longer require the JDK: they run just fine with just the JRE.

@Rekin mentioned another good example: Maven uses the JDK because it actually compiles Java code.

Comment: *"A good example where old versions of Apache Tomcat: it used the Java compiler bundled with the JDK to compile JSP code into bytecode. For this it used `tools.jar` which is included in the JDK but doesn't get delivered with the JRE."*  The `tools.jar` is also  required for compilation using the [`JavaCompiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) of JSE 6+.

Comment: Right, that's the standardized API for the kind of thing that Tomcat was doing.

Answer (score 2):

One application I worked on was using the JDK to compile automatically generated java and load it for user after that (a db-oriented compiler/runner).

@Joachim has a more complete answer.