# Java won't work (Possibly related to installing QTP)

Tags: java, eclipse, qtp

I was working on eclipse two days ago, and closed it properly.
Now, when I'm trying to start it, I get the splash screen popping for a blink of an eye, then disappearing.

I get:

- no error message, and
- no error is logged in the `<workspace>\.metadata\.log` file (the last errors logged there are from two days ago).

Apparently, the problem isn't with the workspace, because I changed the `SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG` argument in `<eclipse>\configurations\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` to `true`, and it doesn't even get as far as showing the dialog.

There's only one thing I can recall I did before it stopped working - I have installed a plugin for UFT Java Extensibility SDK from HP.
Needless to say uninstalling it didn't help.

Is there any other log I can hope to find helpful?
Or anything else I can do to get it to work?

**EDIT:**

I was just trying to start another instance of eclipse I have (`adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219`), and got the same outcome.

**EDIT:**

I added Java & QTP to the title in order to help others who bumps into the same issue.

Comment: Try running with the [`-consoleLog`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html) option and see if that sheds any light.

Comment: Thanks. already tried `-consoleLog`, `-clean` and `-noExit`. all endded up the same way.

Comment: Absolutely nothing on the command line? Oh well, I'm out of ideas then! :-(

Comment: Well, that makes both of us. Thanks @PeterK.

Comment: You are saying two eclipses in you computer, that have nothing to do with each other, can't start and show no error?

Comment: Yes @acdcjunior, unfortunately...

Comment: Have you tried if java in general is working?

Comment: And made sure you have ownership and execute permissions on all of the .exe and .dll files?

Comment: @Arne, you are right - Java is not working. I tried to reinstall jre and it didn't work. what do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed with Java (Thanks Arne). Re-installing the jre didn't help, so I also tried to deleted the JAVA_OPTIONS and JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS enviroment variables, which solved the problem.

Later, I found this discussion which seems related to my problem: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/Environment-variables-JAVA-OPTIONS-and-JAVA-TOOL-OPTIONS-is/td-p/5855995.

I will look more deeply into it later, when I will start using HP's plugin, but I hope this thread can help others who run into trouble with eclipse after installing this plugin.

Comment: Interesting feedback. +1. You didn't need to install and reference a JDK, then?

Answer (score 1):

If the JRE is somehow the issue, try [installing a **JDK**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) [(not a JRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/250517/6309), in a non-default path (for instance, `C:\Prog\Java\JDK1.7.0_xx`), and make sure your [`eclipse.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse) explicitly reference that JDK.

```
-vm
C:/Prog/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
```

(you can use '/' even on Windows in an `eclipse.ini` file)