# If a source code is not inside JDK's src.zip, does it mean it's not open source?

Tags: java

I want to see the source code of sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl#read function. But there's no corresponding source in src.zip of Oracle's JDK.

I know I can see it from the OpenJDK's openjdk-6-src-b27-26_oct_2012.tar.gz downloaded from http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/.

But does it mean that I can't get it from the more popular non-open JDK because it's not open source? Or I'm missing something and I actually can get it from Oracle JDK?(I don't know much of the difference of JDK and OpenJDK)

---

Update:
I don't understand why Oracle didn't include all the sources in src.zip since one can get it from OpenJDK. What do they want to hide? I think if any source if not in the src.zip, it means that Oracle use "some closed source third party components" or "commercial features" for that. Right?

Quote from https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/java_7_questions_answers:

> " Q: Where can I find the source code? A: The source code for the Java
>   SE 7 Reference Implementation is available from the JDK 7 Project in
>   the OpenJDK Community.
>
> Q: What is the difference between the source code found in the OpenJDK
>   repository, and the code you use to build the Oracle JDK?    A: It is
>   very close - our build process for Oracle JDK releases builds on
>   OpenJDK 7 by adding just a couple of pieces, like the deployment code,
>   which includes Oracle's implementation of the Java Plugin and Java
>   WebStart, as well as some closed source third party components like a
>   graphics rasterizer, some open source third party components, like
>   Rhino, and a few bits and pieces here and there, like additional
>   documentation or third party fonts. Moving forward, our intent is to
>   open source all pieces of the Oracle JDK except those that we consider
>   commercial features such as JRockit Mission Control (not yet available
>   in Oracle JDK), and replace encumbered third party components with
>   open source alternatives to achieve closer parity between the code
>   bases."

Comment: if you are going to know differences check this [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547458/what-is-differences-between-jvm-jdk-jre-openjdk

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java SE 6 vs. JRE 1.6 vs. JDK 1.6 - What do these mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250517/java-se-6-vs-jre-1-6-vs-jdk-1-6-what-do-these-mean)

Comment: @Jayan I don't think it's a dup. That one has nothing to do with mine. I'm not asking about difference between jdk and jre. It's more about jdk and open jdk.

Answer (score 0):

Even you find source in src.zip, it does not mean it is open source. OpenSource is more about licensing. You should visit appropriate license agreement at owners site.  See a detailed discussion https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/52534/can-we-use-java-for-commercial-use

[In this case.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/nio/ch/SocketChannelImpl.java), IMHO, license is GNU General Public License version 2.