# Setting JAVA_HOME in Windows?

Tags: java, java-home

Where should **JAVA_HOME** be pointing to - JDK or JRE? I have seen that in few websites. It is set to JRE and in others it is to JDK. And is it dependant on Java version in any way?

Comment: JAVA_HOME should point to JDK. JRE_HOME should point to JRE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDK stands for Java Development Kit, while JRE stands for Java Runtime Environment. JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE as the JDK is used for development purposes. JDK includes the compiler and other tools needed to develop Java applications while JRE does not.

See [How to set java_home on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7) on how to change your JAVA_HOME.

Source:
[Java SE 6 vs. JRE 1.6 vs. JDK 1.6 - What do these mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250517/java-se-6-vs-jre-1-6-vs-jdk-1-6-what-do-these-mean)

Answer (score 1):

You should set `JAVA_HOME` to the JDK.

[Relevant Documentation:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3208/6neopagg5/index.html)

> 1. Install the JDK software.
>
>    a. Go to http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp.
>
>    b. Select the appropriate JDK software and click Download.
>
>    The JDK software is installed on your computer, for example, at
>      C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02. You can move the JDK software to
>      another location if desired.
> 2. To set JAVA_HOME:
>
>    a. Right click My Computer and select Properties.
>
>    b. On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables, and then edit
>      JAVA_HOME to point to where the JDK software is located, for example,
>      C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02.

Answer (score 0):

1-Right click desktop ->Show More Options ->Personelize->System-->About-->Advanced System Setting-->Environment variables-->

user variables ...
JAVA_HOME  C:\Program Files\java\jdk-19      --> ok CLİCK

System variables ...
Path ->New -> C:\Program Files\java\jdk-19 \bin