# Which JVM architecture am I using?

Tags: java, eclipse

I followed https://www.guru99.com/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu.html to install Java on my 64-bit, x86, Ubuntu 18.04 system.

When I run "java -version", I get the output :

```
ariba@monster:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
```

What does "Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)" mean? Is my JVM architecture 64-bit or 32-bit ? And what architecture of eclipse-installer should I use, then?

Comment: Which one did you install?  x86 is 32-bit, x64 is 64-bit. I'm not sure about the HotSpot server, I'd have to look that up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java SE 6 vs. JRE 1.6 vs. JDK 1.6 - What do these mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250517/java-se-6-vs-jre-1-6-vs-jdk-1-6-what-do-these-mean), but I didn't actually see an explanation there about 32 vs. 64 bit.

Comment: Try `java -fullversion`; and I believe "Server" is **always** 64-bit. And HotSpot means you are using an Oracle JRE.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ```ariba@monster:~$ java -fullversion
java full version "1.8.0_231-b11"```

Comment: @PaulT. x86 it is. *Facepalm*

Comment: @PaulT. Any way to easily uninstall this and install the right version?? I had already wasted quite a lot of time setting this up.

Comment: Looking at the information from your link, it looks like all that was done was extract the downloaded tar.gz to a directory, and then setup various environment variables? If so, then it should be a simple matter to remove the directory that was extracted previously, extract the x64 one instead, and then update the environment references for the new (x64) directory. (from step 3 onwards from that link)

Comment: @PaulT. There's also java,javac,javaws binaries in /usr/bin . Should I try to remove them too, or they would get overwritten as I install the new version??

Comment: Looks like your link info will update those based on step 7?

Comment: @PaulT. Yes, it worked

Answer (score 0):

1. The Java HotSpot Virtual Machine is a core component of the Java SE platform. It implements the Java Virtual Machine Specification, and is delivered as a shared library in the Java Runtime Environment. So, HotSpot is an "ergonomic" JVM. Read more detail here, [link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136373.html).
2. JVM architecture which you post in the question is 32-bit. You can get `64-Bit` info in the output if you JDK is 64-bit architecture.

   ```
   λ java -version                                                  
   java version "1.8.0_101"                                         
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)            
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
   ```
3. Just getting the latest 64-bit version eclipse. The architecture of eclipse-installer depends on your system architecture.